# Findcontrol failed for templatefield (linkbutton) in detailsView

Tags: asp.net

I would like to set a templatefield (linkbutton) to invisible when the DetailsView is not in ReadOnly mode.  I created a linkbutton to replace the auto-gen "delete" button and want to hide it when editing and inserting.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="resultDetailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="smo_code,id"
    DataSourceID="detailviewDataSource" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemInserting="resultDetailsView_ItemInserting"
    OnItemUpdating="resultDetailsView_ItemUpdating" OnItemUpdated="resultDetailsView_ItemUpdated"
    OnItemDeleted="resultDetailsView_ItemDeleted" OnItemInserted="resultDetailsView_ItemInserted"
    OnItemDeleting="resultDetailsView_ItemDeleting" OnModeChanging="resultDetailsView_ModeChanging"
    OnDataBound="resultDetailsView_DataBound" OnItemCommand="resultDetailsView_ItemCommand">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="event" HeaderText="event" SortExpression="event" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteLink" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                    OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

IN CODE BEHIND, FINDCONTROL returned null:

```
protected void resultDetailsView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton deleteLink = (LinkButton)resultDetailsView.FindControl("deleteLink");
    if (resultDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly)
    {
        deleteLink.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        deleteLink.Visible = false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it after .DataBind() method. Here is a good example 
[How to dynamically hide fields in a DetailsView (fields count is always 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385599/how-to-dynamically-hide-fields-in-a-detailsview-fields-count-is-always-0)

Or even this too is a good example
[Listview/DetailsView: Hide a null field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493048/listview-detailsview-hide-a-null-field)

Comment: Sorry!  My case is not resolved.  It generated "ReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for the deleteLink.  Where should the DataBind() applied?  Would show the way more, many thanks!